# zk Listbox ListCell textbox password getValue

Tags: java, textbox, zk

hello i have a zul like this

```
<listcell sclass="textColumn"><textbox type="password" value="*+*+*+*+"/></listcell>
<listcell sclass="textColumn"><textbox type="password" value="*+*+*+*+"/></listcell>
```

as you can see i am setting the value of textbox value="++++" on records coming from the DB but i have a button set a new record on it using this code

```
model.add(clazz);
```

of course after the rendering i have cleaning both inputs values to null.[when adding a new record]

when i try to save the records on DB i am checking in zul the values of the 2 inputs and i getting the right values the user input values but when i get the listBox in Java Code i am getting still "++++" on both inputs this is driving me nuts

here is my code

```
(Textbox)((Listcell)(item.getChildren().get(5))).getFirstChild()).getValue();
(Textbox)((Listcell)(item.getChildren().get(6))).getFirstChild()).getValue();
```

both are returning "++++" on other hand the previously added items from DB i can modify and i can see the new values the problem comes when i add a new item set to null my question is

```
((Textbox)((Listcell)(item.getChildren().get(5))).getFirstChild()).setValue(null);      
((Textbox)((Listcell)(item.getChildren().get(6))).getFirstChild()).setValue(null);
```

if this is not working why i am checking null values on afterRender.

this is the values i am receiving

```
onAfterRender:start[after set the values to null both empty this is in .zul]

onAfterRender:end

onBeforeSend:start[after the inputs of the user before going to Controller this is in .zul].
qwerty qwerty
onBeforeSend:end

inJava:start[the values i am receiving in the listbox before going to save them in this is in .Java]
*+*+*+*+<--Java-->*+*+*+*+ 
inJava:end
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using MVC ? You can do this in MVVM very easily See this  [ZK Listbox](http://zkframeworkhint.blogspot.in/2013/02/zk-set-desire-selection-in-listbox-model.html) may be it will help you to USE MVVM for Item rendered you can check this example[ZK Listbox ItemRendered Example](http://zkframeworkhint.blogspot.in/)